# intellisense + hasOwnProperty in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode + typescript:

```
let o = {
    a: 100
}
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty("a"));
```

If an object literal is created, I had the expectation, that methods like `hasOwnProperty()` or `toString()` appear in the Intellisense preview. But they don't.

Is it possible to show these methods in the the Intellisense?

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't tell TypeScript the type of object it tries to infer them from what it knows. Let's have a look at your sample code:

```
let o = {
  a: 100
}
```

When TypeScript sees code like this it automatically infers an interface that looks like this:

```
interface O {
  a: number;
}
```

What you gain is that if you type `o.a` you get a suggestion that tells you that `o.a` is of type number. Now if you want to have access to methods like `hasOwnProperty` they have to be defined on that interface. TypeScript comes with such an interface called `Object`.

Try the following:

```
interface O extends Object {
  a: number;
}

var o: O = {
  a: 100
};
```

Now you have all methods that are defined by the `Object` interface as well as your own properties such as `a` in this example. In case you're just interested in the `Object` interface you don't have to define a new interface but simply use it:

```
var o: Object = {
  a: 100
};
```

But beware that `o.a` in this case doesn't make the compiler happy.

This should make IntelliSense work for you. ;)